# Validating String

Tags: java, validation, while-loop

```
 */
package controller;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author dylan
 */
public class Controller {

    public Controller() {
        getUserInput();
    }// end of controller


    private void getUserInput() {
        String color = "";
       boolean isColor;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a primary color: blue, red, or yellow.");
        color = input.nextLine();

        do{
            if (input.hasNextLine()) {
                color = input.nextLine();
                isColor = true;
            }
              else {
                System.out.println("Thats not a primary color");
                isColor = false;
                }
        }
        while(!(isColor));
        System.out.println(color);



    }



}// end class
```

i need to validate string color to only be blue red or yellow but im not exactly sure how to set it to only those colors

Answer (score 2):

make your do while like this

```
do{
      System.out.println("Please enter a primary color: blue, red, or yellow.");
      color = input.nextLine();
      if (color.equals("blue")|| color.equals("red") || color.equals("yellow")) {

            isColor = true;
         } else {
                    System.out.println("Thats not a primary color");
                    isColor = false;
                    }
            }
            while(!(isColor));
            System.out.println(color);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
String color = "";
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
do{
     System.out.println("Please enter a primary color: blue, red, or yellow or nothing to exit:");
     color = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();

     if ("blue".equals(color) || "red".equals(color) || "yellow".equals(color)) {
         System.out.println("The color " + color + " is CORRECT!\n");
     }
     else { 
         if (!"".equals(color) ) {
             System.out.println("WRONG - The color " + color + " is not a primary color!\n");
         }
    }
} while(!"".equals(color));
input.close();
System.out.println("Program Terminated!");
```

**EDIT:**

whoops...JRowan beat me to it :) I should have refreshed the page :/